# React-Native Button On Press doesn't work

Tags: javascript, button, react-native, onpress

I can't bind my onPress method to my JSX button. 
I've tried already tons of different solutions but none of them worked.

onPress Method:

```
class ScreenEnterPlayerNames extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Player Names',
  };

  onPressStartTheGame = () => {
    console.log("Pushed button Start the Game!")
    //dispatch({ type: ADD_PLAYER_NAME, playerNumber: 5, playerName: "Sandro" })
  }
```

Button:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.viewMain}>
        <View style={styles.viewTxt}>
          <Text style={styles.TxtHeading}>
            Please enter the names in sequence.
          </Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.viewTextBox}>
          {textBoxes}
        </ScrollView>

        <View style={styles.viewButton}>
          <Button
            title='Start the Game!'
            onPress={() => this.onPressStartTheGame}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried it with following approaches as well:

```
onPress={this.onPressStartTheGame}
onPress={this.onPressStartTheGame()}
onPress={this.onPressStartTheGame.bind(this)}
onPress={() => this.onPressStartTheGame.bind(this)}
```

And I tried to change the function to:

```
onPressStartTheGame()  {...
```

So I am pretty sure there is something else wrong but I can't figure out what.

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your method

```
 onPressStartTheGame(){
    console.log("Pushed button Start the Game!")
    //dispatch({ type: ADD_PLAYER_NAME, playerNumber: 5, playerName: "Sandro" })
  }
```

and call it like

```
onPress={this.onPressStartTheGame.bind(this)}
```

here you can double check and try the behave in a sandbox.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html

Comment: Thats working perfect thanks! Still not sure why it didn't work with the other methods. Thanks!